# Twilio not detecting DTMF tones from Skype

Tags: twilio, voip, skype, dtmf

Twilio not detecting my DTMF tones from Skype.

- We have setup an IVR system with twilio whereby clients must enter a
  7 digit client number.
- Some of our clients phone from voip phones,
  therefore we need to ensure that twilio can detect the DTMF tones
  properly (most use Skype so that is our primary concern right now).
- Twilio IVR detects tones fine from mobile or landline phones.
- Calling other IVR systems from our Skype clients works just fine

Entered a support case w/ Twilio but so far they have not been helpful so I'd like to poll the StackOverflow community.

Versions of Skype tested (at various different physical locations):

- Skype version 7.4.0.104 on Windows 8
- Skype version 8.11.0.4 on MAC OSX Sierra

To make matters more confusing for us, about 20% of the calls that we make via Skype it DOES accept the tones. The other 80% of the time the calls are not recognizing the tones.

We believe this to be a problem with either Twilio accepting DTMF tones from voip phones OR something that is running inconsistently in our Twilio scripting. Because we can dial other IVR systems and enter codes fine with Skype, it doesn't appear to be a problem with Skype.

In our TwiML voice scripting we are using GATHER. Here is a sample of our gather code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
      <Gather action="clientcode.jsp" timeout="15">
        <Say>Please enter your client code.</Say>
      </Gather>
      <Redirect method="GET">gatherfields.jsp</Redirect>
    </Response>
```

Any advice or direction to point us in is helpful.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm sorry you're having trouble with this. Your TwiML looks correct though, so I don't think it's a problem on your end. I can't tell which your ticket is regarding this, if you need someone to follow up with support to push this along, feel free to send me your ticket number at philnash@twilio.com. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @philnash. Email sent!

Comment: Was there any resolution to this, I've been trying to get DTMF to work as well?

Comment: Unfortunately not. No resolution that was adequate. It appears not to be Twilio's fault, but rather Microsoft !@$#'ing up royally with the latest version of Skype. The new version of Skype apparently sends the DTMF tones in a different fashion. Let me know if you hear of a workaround or discover one. This is incredibly annoying for our customers that we support. The best Microsoft could offer was "Please delete and then re-install Skype" - which did not fix the problem. the tech engineer mentioned "they were experiencing problems in their office with Skype dialing extensions"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for several months. After a laborious but fruitful exchange with Skype Support (Virtual Assistant, subsequent email exchanges with several Skype Support people, Remote Desktop Control, etc!) the support team eventually figured out that there is an issue with the Subtitles Function. They have now updated the FAQ here:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34713/faq-and-known-issues-with-skype

When making a call and using the Dial Pad to select the option for Touch Tones, they will not work if you have subtitles enabled on the call.

To workaround this issue simply disable subtitles: Select your profile picture > Settings > Calling > Call Subtitles, then turn off the option to Show subtitles for all voice and video calls.

Note: If you don't have the option turned on to Show subtitles for all voice and video calls but have turned subtitles on for an individual call, starting a new call with your contact will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you are using the iOS Skype app to test this, open the app and do the DTMF in the Skype app's keypad. Don't use the iOS default call, it won't work.